# how to pass the value in protractor like this element(by.model('filter.dateRange')).$('[value="<parameter>")

Tags: angularjs, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I need to pass the value say in the below example as 'date' to identify the element in the page.
I am working with Angularjs page automation using protractor with Javascript.

```
function(parameter) {
    element(by.model('filter.dateRange')).$('[value="parameter"]');
}
```

How to give the value in the above expression from the function call.
i.e, How to pass different values to the parameter. now parameter becomes string.

Comment: Do you know these dates inside Protractor test? Are they hard-coded?

Comment: why do you want to pass parameters here , can you explain more

Comment: we have different values in dateRange dropdown. and I have to select according to the test case.

Comment: Is date range a select dropdown ?

Comment: yes its a dropdown list. I am able to select the value in the dropdown from the hardcoded value like element(by.model('filter.dateRange')).$('[value="Yesterday"]');. but i need to pass different values to it.

Comment: @Yugesh Use a array variable in place of parameter string and try to loop it through all the values of that variable. `var parameter; element(by.model('filter.dateRange')).$('[value="+parameter+"]');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a array variable in place of parameter string and try to loop it through all the values of that variable. Additionally if you are working on the result of finding the element, you should be using **then** functionality of protractor. Here's the link to it - [then-protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=then)

```
var parameter = ['Yesterday', 'today']; //fill in your values
function(parameter) {
    var func = function(val){
        element(by.model('filter.dateRange')).$('[value="+parameter[val]+"]');
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < parameter.length; ++i) {
        func[i];
    };
};
```

Hope this helps.